# Does SquishIt support SASS?

Tags: asp.net, css, squishit

I'm using [SquishIt 0.8.7 from Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/SquishIt/0.8.7).

But it doesn't seem to pick up my .sass or .scss files. It works perfectly with .less files (utilising dotLess).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in alpha apparently:

https://nuget.org/packages/SquishIt.Sass/0.9.0-alpha1

Answer (score 0):

0.9 will be the first version to support Sass/Scss (though it will be through an additional package linked above).  There is an issue with the code included in the above package for WebActivator (it references an incorrect namespace) but expect this to be fixed soon.